# prediction using mixed logit model in R

Tags: random, coefficients

I am interested in using mixed logit model for prediction. Is there a function/ package in R that can do it for me? If not, how is it approached mathematically. I understand that the coefficients are random, therefore, a very naive approach is to draw from the distribution of betas and take mean for out of sample Xs.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

> [`mlogit`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/mlogit.pdf) is a package for R which enables the estimation of random utility models with individual and/or alternative speciﬁc variables. The main extensions of the basic multinomial model (heteroscedastic, nested and random parameter models) are implemented.

**Some useful references:**

- [Kenneth Train's exercises for `mlogit`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/Exercises.pdf)
- [Estimation of Random Utility Models in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/mlogit2.pdf) by Yves Croissant

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could not find a predict function for mixed logit in Yves's mlogit package. Can you please point me to the exact answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `predict` function directly

```
library("mlogit")
data("Mode", package="mlogit")
Mo <- mlogit.data(Mode, choice = 'choice', shape = 'wide', 
              varying = c(2:9))  
# starting values of the beta coefficients
strt <- c(1.83086600, -1.28168186,  0.30935104, -0.41344010, -0.04665517,  
          1,0.25997237,0.73648694,  1.30789474, -0.79818416,  0.43013035)
p1 <- mlogit(choice ~ cost + time, Mo, seed = 20, 
         R = 100, probit = TRUE, start = strt)

Mo2 <- Mo
Mo2[Mo2$alt == 'car', 'cost'] <- Mo2[Mo2$alt == 'car', 'cost'] * 2
newShares <- apply(predict(p1, newdata = Mo2), 2, mean)
```

hope this answers your question